# Register a task for another user logon

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I run a powershell script as Admiministrator, and I want to register a scheduled task for another user to run at logon.

The following powershell code will register an event for the Adiministrator user:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "NotepadLaunch" -Description "Launch notepad at logon"
```

I see that the New-ScheduledTaskTrigger supports the -User option:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649821.aspx

```
User<String>

Specifies the identifier of the user for a trigger that starts a task when a user logs on.
```

Unfortunately the documentation is not very clear, and it doesn't seem to work as I would expect (setting the user where the action is triggered).

My question: is it possible to specify a different user when scheduling a task?

There are other suitable alternatives to set a command to be launched when another user logs on (assuming I'm using the Administrator user to set the command)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested on Server 2012 and Powershell 3.0

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn -User "DOMAIN\username"
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "NotepadLaunch" -Description "Launch notepad at logon" -User "DOMAIN\username"
```

Comment: So this seems to work. I suppose my problem stems from the fact that the user has no permission to run the command I want to schedule.